# How to git add multiple files from same folder without re-typing folder name?

Tags: git

I had to write `git add src/index.css src/logo.svg`, repeating 'src/' multiple times.

Is there a way that I can `git add` multiple files from the same folder without having to type the same folder name for every file?

Comment: `git add src/*`

Comment: @PaulBradbury I don't want to add all files from /src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case,

```
cd src
git add index.css logo.svg
```

If there are not any irrelevant files under `src/`,

```
git add src
```

or

```
cd src
git add .
```

By the irrelevant files, I mean the untracked files that are not ignored. There could be some new files under `src/` just for test. If they are not ignored, `git add src` or `git add .` will add them too, which is not expected. If a file is added by mistake, one of the solutions is

```
git reset path/to/file
```

Suppose there is only a small number of irrelevant files, `foo.js` and `bar.js`, we can also add all and exclude them by

```
cd src
git add . -- ':!foo.js' ':!bar.js'
```

If we use `git add .` or `git add folder`, better is to always run `git status` and have a check.

If the files you want to add have already been tracked before, not new untracked files, we can skip `git add` and use `git commit -a` to add and commit them in one step. For a new untracked file, we need to explicitly add it.